# Qual a origem da expressão "dar pau"?

Tags: etimologia, português-brasileiro, expressões

No Brasil, a expressão "dar pau" pode ter vários significados.

- Se o computador parou de funcionar, deu pau;
- se João estar prestes a bater em Pedro, João dará um pau em Pedro;
- ou até conotação sexual

Qual é a origem dessa expressão com o significado de não funcionar?

Comment: Limitei isto a português-brasileiro, porque em Portugal, «dar pau» significa «dar caneladas», só. Não tem esses significados.

Comment: Pela raiz, "dar pau" nos sentidos de "açoitar" ou "fazer sexo", parecem ser expressões verbais relacionadas (e com mesmo radical) aos nomes "paulada" (açoitamento) e "pau" (órgão sexual masculino), tendo o mesmo desenvolvimento semântico que a expressão "descer o cacete", que também pode referir tanto a "açoitar" quanto a "fazer sexo" (sendo que cacete denota um pau/bastão de açoite ou o órgão sexual masculino). Já a origem do uso de "dar pau" como "enguiçar", não é tão óbvio quanto as outras duas acepções, mas imagino que tenha vindo de "fazer enguiçar a pauladas".

Comment: Deve ser por causa de barulho que equipamentos geram ao dar pau.

Comment: pau poder ser pénis, sim. Mas nunca ouvi dar pau para dizer relações sexuais. Não se encontra aqui, https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/pau